# Complex headers in angular2-data-table

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

I'm trying to create a table with a complex header (multi-line header) like this:

[image: complexheader]
using the angular-2-data-table library found here:
https://github.com/swimlane/angular2-data-table

They have something called "Expressive cell templates" in which you can define columns like this:

```
 <datatable
    class="material"
    [rows]="rows"
    [options]="options">
    <datatable-column name="Name">
      <template let-column="column">
        Hi + {{column.name}}
      </template>
      <template let-value="value">
        Hi: <strong>{{value}}</strong>
      </template>
    </datatable-column>
    <datatable-column name="Gender">
      <template let-row="row" let-value="value">
        My name is: <i [innerHTML]="row['name']"></i> and <i>{{value}}</i>
        <div>{{joke}}</div>
      </template>
    </datatable-column>
  </datatable>
```

[plnkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iH1e7cIAdX5Ds4jY7WYc)

But it seems like the column name is always defined as text, and it's unclear how you would have nested column names. Any ideas if complex headers are possible in angular2-data-table? It's possible in regular datatables (https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/complex_header.html).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same problem here actually, would love it if anybody had any ideas?

Comment: I'm the author of the proj, its not possible at the moment but were looking into adding it to the roadmap.